# Is it possible to get this collection with only one find() call?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i would like to get a collection of documents with a specific one included (i have the `_id` field of this document).

The difficulty is to also get the 3 documents which precede and follow this document (in the inserting order).

I really doubt it is possible in one request because if i use the `where` rule to match the id of the document i want to get, i don't know how i could also match the other ones.

So i know i could do one `find` for the document and get the 3 oldest and newest with another `find` refering the date of the `created_at` field, but i am interesting to know if i can improve this treatment.

Comment: when you say you have id do you mean your own custom Id or the MongoDB generated _id field?

Comment: I mean i have the _id mongoDB field.

Comment: you can extract timestamp from _id though you still can't query for top three less than *and* top three greater than in one "find".  You might be able to do this with aggregation framework maybe - what's behind wanting to only do one query?  speed? or simplicity?

Comment: Could you add an indexed field for insertion order to your docs and key off that?